When opening an xlsx file with ClosedXML in C#, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException
I'm using the latest version of ClosedXML from NuGet: .102.3.  I can open some spreadsheets with ClosedXML, but there are many which I cannot.
New information: I went to the ClosedXML site and got the 'develop' version.  I get a different error, but do not receive this error.  I will work with those developers.  This question can be closed.
I receive the following exception from either a network drive or a local drive.:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException HResult=0x80131502 Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: A: is not recognized as a column letter Source=ClosedXML StackTrace: at ClosedXML.Excel.XLHelper.GetColumnNumberFromLetter(String columnLetter) at ClosedXML.Excel.XLAddress.Create(XLWorksheet worksheet, String cellAddressString) at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadCells(SharedStringItem\[\] sharedStrings, Stylesheet s, NumberingFormats numberingFormats, Fills fills, Borders borders, Fonts fonts, Dictionary`2 sharedFormulasR1C1, XLWorksheet ws, Dictionary`2 styleList, Cell cell, Int32 rowIndex) at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadRows(Stylesheet s, NumberingFormats numberingFormats, Fills fills, Borders borders, Fonts fonts, XLWorksheet ws, SharedStringItem\[\] sharedStrings, Dictionary`2 sharedFormulasR1C1, Dictionary`2 styleList, Row row) at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSpreadsheetDocument(SpreadsheetDocument dSpreadsheet) at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSheets(String fileName) at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook..ctor(String file, LoadOptions loadOptions) at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook..ctor(String file) at ClosedXML.Test.ClosedXML.Open() in C:\\Data\\Visual Studio\\ClosedXML\\ClosedXML.Test\\ClosedXML.cs:line 16

Has anyone seen this problem?

Go to GitHub and download a later version.  I didn't get the same error.  Still working with another error.
